# Merge multiple rows into a column while replacing the keys with a 'name' field from the original table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a join table that has 'account_id' and 'group id' in it, both represented by a GUID. I'm trying to merge the columns so we get a single 'account_id' with all of it's 'group_id's merged to a single Colum/row, but display the actual name of the account and group.

Tables
Account

```
account_id   Name
1            Henry
2            Smith
```

Group

```
Group_id   Group_nameName
3            User
4            Admin
```

Account_Group_Join_Table

```
account_id   group_id
1            3
1            4
2            3
```

Desired Result:

```
Name    Groups
Henry   Dev,User
Smith   User, Admin
```

Code so far to return 'account_id' with 'group_id' grouped to single row/column

```
select account_id,
  stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + group_id
           FROM account_group_join t2
           where t2.account_id = t1.account_id
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [Groups]
from account_group_join t1
group by account_id
```

Comment: `FOR XML PATH(''))` should be `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` to avoid XML escaping, and `,1,1,''` should be `,1,2,''` or whatever length your separator is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to join to your group table in the subquery so you can get the name rather than the ID. You also may as well just select from `Account` in the outer query and avoid an additional join to account to get the name:

```
SELECT  a.account_id,
        a.Name,
      STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + g.group_nameName
               FROM account_group_join AS ag
                    INNER JOIN [Group] AS g
                        ON g.group_id = ag.group_id
               WHERE ag.account_id = a.account_id
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Groups]
from Account AS a;
```

n.b. I've changed your aliases from `t1` and `t2` to something that kind of represents the table I am aliasing, you'll find this much easier especially when working with larger queries. More reading here: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)